# How to upload an XML file via API Gateway and maintain file encoding

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encoding, aws-api-gateway, encode

I'm having issues uploading XML files via the API Gateway to S3 while maintaining the encoding, which in this case is windows-1250 (long story).

What is happening, is that the XML file is uploading to the S3 bucket, but encoded as UTF-8, which breaks a decoding we need to achieve later in the flow.

I am finding the documentation RE Binary Payloads quite sketchy to make sense of [Support Binary Payloads in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html).

Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction, or provide an example to follow?

Essentially: How to upload an XML file via API Gateway to S3 and maintain the file encoding as is.